# PDO fetch rows with \"

Tags: php, pdo

So i want to get the id of a post where title = "$someTitle"

```
$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NAME",'USER','PASS', 
  array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
  ));


$someTitle = '\"If you\'re absent during my struggle, don\'t expect to be present during my success.\" - Will Smith';

$statement = $dbh->prepare("select id from posts where title = :title");
$statement->execute(array(':title' => $someTitle));
$row = $statement->fetch();

echo $row[id];
```

And this example dosent work, but if i change $someTitle to $someTitle = 'new test';

every thing is ok

Any tips ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do your own escaping. That's why there's prepared statements, which take care of the SQL injection problems for you. With your own escapes in the text, you're telling the DB you want to search for text in the DB which contains those escapes - which most likely is not there.

instead, have:

```
$someTitle = '"If you\'re absent during my struggle, don\'t expect to be present during my success." - Will Smith';
              ^---no escape, and ditto for at the end of the line.
```

Note that I've only un-escaped the `"` characters. Since you're using single-quotes for the string itself, any `'` DO have to be escaped for this to be a valid PHP string assignment. However, the `\'` will NOT be seen by the database, only the raw `'`.